# How to send ffmpeg AVPacket through WebRTC (using libdatachannel)

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, webrtc

I'm encoding a video frame with the `ffmpeg` libraries, generating an `AVPacket` with compressed data.

Thanks to some recent advice here on S/O, I am trying to send that frame over a network using the `WebRTC` library `libdatachannel`, specifically by adapting the example here:

`https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel/tree/master/examples/streamer`

I am seeing problems inside `h264rtppacketizer.cpp` (part of the library, not the example) which are almost certainly to do with how I'm providing the sample data.
(I don't think that this is anything to do with libdatachannel specifically, it will be an issue with what I'm sending)

The example code reads each encoded frame from a file, and populates a `sample` by setting the content of the file to the contents of the file:

`sample = *reinterpret_cast<vector<byte> *>(&fileContents);`

`sample` is just a `std::vector<byte>;`

I have naively copied the contents of an `AVPacket->data` pointer into the `sample` vector:

```
sample.resize(pkt->size);
memcpy(sample.data(), pkt->data, pkt->size * sizeof(std::byte));
```

but the packetizer is falling over when trying to get length values out of that data.
Specifically, in the following code, the first iteration gets a length of 1, but the second, looking up index 5, gives 1119887324. This is way too big for my data, which is only 3526 bytes (the whole frame is a single colour so likely to be small once encoded):

```
while (index < message->size()) {
assert(index + 4 < message->size());
auto lengthPtr = (uint32_t *)(message->data() + index);
uint32_t length = ntohl(*lengthPtr);
auto naluStartIndex = index + 4;
auto naluEndIndex = naluStartIndex + length;
assert(naluEndIndex <= message->size());    
        
auto begin = message->begin() + naluStartIndex;
auto end = message->begin() + naluEndIndex;
nalus->push_back(std::make_shared<NalUnit>(begin, end));
index = naluEndIndex;
}
```

Here is a dump of

```
uint32_t length = ntohl(*lengthPtr);
```

for the first few elements of the message (`*lengthPtr` in parentheses):

```
[2022-03-29 15:12:01.182] [info] index 0: 1  (16777216)
[2022-03-29 15:12:01.183] [info] index 1: 359  (1728118784)
[2022-03-29 15:12:01.184] [info] index 2: 91970  (1114046720)
[2022-03-29 15:12:01.186] [info] index 3: 23544512  (3225577217)
[2022-03-29 15:12:01.186] [info] index 4: 1732427807  (532693607)
[2022-03-29 15:12:01.187] [info] index 5: 1119887324  (3693068354)
[2022-03-29 15:12:01.188] [info] index 6: 3223313413  (98312128)
[2022-03-29 15:12:01.188] [info] index 7: 534512896  (384031)
[2022-03-29 15:12:01.188] [info] index 8: 3691315291  (1526728156)
[2022-03-29 15:12:01.189] [info] index 9: 83909537  (2707095557)
[2022-03-29 15:12:01.189] [info] index 10: 6004992  (10574592)
[2022-03-29 15:12:01.190] [info] index 11: 1537277952  (41307)
[2022-03-29 15:12:01.190] [info] index 12: 2701131779  (50331809)
[2022-03-29 15:12:01.192] [info] index 13: 768  (196608)
```

(I know I should post a complete sample, I am working on it)

- I am fairly sure I am just missing something basic. E.g. am I supposed to do something with the `AVPacket` `side_data`, does AVPacket have or miss some header info?
- If I just `fwrite` the `pkt->data` for a single frame to disk, I can read the codec information with `ffprobe`:

```
Input #0, h264, from 'encodedOut.h264':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 30 tbr, 1200k tbn
```

Update: This issue is solved by changing the `H264RtpPacketizer` separator setting from `H264RtpPacketizer::Separator::Length` to `H264RtpPacketizer::Separator::LongStartSequence`, many thanks to author of libdatachannel [paullouisageneau](https://github.com/paullouisageneau) (see answer below)

I have issues related to settings for the `libx264` encoder, but can happily encode with `h264_nvenc` and `h264_mf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input files of the [streamer example](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel/tree/master/examples/streamer) for [libdatachannel](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel) use 32-bit length as NAL unit separator. Therefore, the `H264RtpPacketizer` instance is created with `H264RtpPacketizer::Separator::Length`.

If I'm not mistaken the ffmpeg output will have 4-byte start sequences as NAL unit prefix instead (which is actually more common), so if you change the packetizer setting to `H264RtpPacketizer::Separator::LongStartSequence` it should accept your sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ffmpeg for h264 encoding, sometimes ffmpeg will use `00 00 01` for start sequence, and `H264RtpPacketizer::Separator::LongStartSequence` will only accept `00 00 00 01`, use `H264RtpPacketizer::Separator::StartSequence` can solve this problem.